# Doctrine MappingException with message 'The target-entity Entity\\ItemsBags cannot be found in 'Entity\\Players#itemsBag'

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, backend

Good day. I'm already on my second day and I can not understand what's the matter ... I get the error in runtime:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'The
>   target-entity Entity\ItemsBags cannot be found in
>   'Entity\Players#itemsBag'.' in
>   /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php:762
>       Stack trace: 
>       #0./var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataInfo.php(1028):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException::invalidTargetEntityClass('Entity\\ItemsBag...',
>   'Entity\\Players', 'itemsBag')
>       #1./var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(272):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo->validateAssociations()
>       #2./var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(251):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->validateRuntimeMetadata(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata),
>   NULL)
>       #3./var/www/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(332):
>   Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadM in
>   /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php
>   on line 762

When I check the doctrine, and the update, everything goes well:

> root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema:update --force Updating
>   database schema... Database schema updated successfully! "4" queries
>   were executed

---

> root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:validate-schema [Mapping]  OK
>   - The mapping files are correct. [Database] OK - The database schema is in sync with the mapping files.

**I tried** to clear the cache, delete the proxy and regenerate them, but nothing produced results ...

```
root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:metadata
Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries
Successfully deleted cache entries.
root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:query
Clearing ALL Query cache entries
Successfully deleted cache entries.
root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:clear-cache:result
Clearing ALL Result cache entries
Successfully deleted cache entries.
root@comp:# php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-proxies
Processing entity "Entity\Objects"
Processing entity "Entity\Weapons"
Processing entity "Entity\ItemsBags"
Processing entity "Entity\Players"
Processing entity "Entity\Translations"
Processing entity "Entity\Worlds"
Processing entity "Entity\Tiles"
Processing entity "Entity\WorldStructures"

Proxy classes generated to "/tmp"
```

**Players.php**

```
namespace Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="players")
 *
 */
class Players{

    ...

    /**
     * @var ItemsBags
     *
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ItemsBags", mappedBy="player")
     */
    private $itemsBag;

    ...
}
```

**ItemsBags.php**

```
namespace Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 *
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="item_bags")
 *
 */
class ItemsBags{

    ...

    /**
     * @var Players
     *
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Players", inversedBy="itemsBag")
     * @JoinColumn(name="player_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $player;

    ...

}
```

Tell me please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd try removing the @JoinColumn line to see if that helps.

Comment: It takes no effect(

Comment: You could try using the fully qualified names: `@OneToOne(targetEntity="\Entity\ItemsBags", mappedBy="player")` and `@OneToOne(targetEntity="\Entity\Players", inversedBy="itemsBag")`. Though it does seem to be looking for them there...

Comment: Have you configured the psr-4 root? Look for psr-4 in your composer file

Comment: I try to using the fully qualified names, but this too no effect.
@Sarcoma I did not quite understand your question... I use only doctrine in my project, using composer. I initialize doctrine like this: https://pastebin.com/AYB7Zvnd

Comment: @Sarcoma can you show me, how I must declare my entinties in autoload section of my composer.json?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Sarcoma. I just forgot to specify autoload section in my composer.json

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "core/" }
  },
```

---

P.S Can enyone me tell, why my project running normal before?) Before I too have many entinties, no have that section in my composer.json, but all works fine.